# Vue.js 3 Pinia store is only partially reactive. Why?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuedraggable

I'm using Pinia as Store for my Vue 3 application. The problem is that the store reacts on some changes, but ignores others.

**The store looks like that:**

```js
state: () => {
  return {
    roles: [],
    currentRole: 'Administrator',
    elements: []
  }
},
getters: {
  getElementsForCurrentRole: (state) => {
    let role = state.roles.find((role) => role.label == state.currentRole);
    if (role) {
      return role.permissions.elements;
    }
  }
},
```

**In the template file, I communicate with the store like this:**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <draggable 
      v-model="getElementsForCurrentRole" 
      group="elements" 
      @end="onDragEnd" 
      item-key="name">
      <template #item="{element}">
        <n-card :title="formatElementName(element.name)" size="small" header-style="{titleFontSizeSmall: 8px}" hoverable>
          <n-switch v-model:value="element.active" size="small" />
        </n-card>
      </template>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { NCard, NSwitch } from 'naive-ui';
  import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
  import { usePermissionsStore } from '@/stores/permissions';
  import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

  const props = defineProps({
    selectedRole: {
      type: String
    }
  })

  const permissionsStore = usePermissionsStore();
  const { getElementsForCurrentRole, roles } = storeToRefs(permissionsStore);

  const onDragEnd = () => {
    permissionsStore.save();
  }
  
  const formatElementName = (element) => {
    let title = element.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + element.slice(1);
    title = title.replace('-', ' ');
    title = title.split(' ');
    if (title[1]) {
      title = title[0] + ' ' + title[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + title[1].slice(1);
    }
    if (typeof title == 'object') {
      return title[0];
    }

    return title;
  }
  
</script>
```

My problem is the `v-model="getElementsForCurrentRole"`. When making changes, for example changing the value for the switch, the store is reactive and the changes are made successfully. But: If I try to change the Array order by dragging, the store does not update the order. I'm confused, because the store reacts on other value changes, but not on the order change.

What can be the issue here? Do I something wrong?

-Edit- I see the following warning on drag: `Write operation failed: computed value is readonly`

**Workaround**

As workaround I work with the drag event and write the new index directly to the store variable. But...its just a workaround. I would really appreciate a cleaner solution.

Here is the workaround code:

```
onDrag = (event) => {
  if (event && event.type == 'end') {
    // Is Drag Event. Save the new order manually directly in the store
    let current = permissionsStore.roles.find((role) => role.value == permissionsStore.currentRole);
    
    var element = current.permissions.elements[event.oldIndex];
    current.permissions.elements.splice(event.oldIndex, 1);
    current.permissions.elements.splice(event.newIndex, 0, element);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put reactive value on v-model.

**getElementsForCurrentRole** is from getters, so it is treated as **computed** value.

> Similar to toRefs() but specifically designed for Pinia stores so
> methods and non reactive properties are completely ignored.
>
> https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#storetorefs

I think this should work for you.

```
// template
v-model="elementsForCurrentRole"  

// script
const { getElementsForCurrentRole, roles } = storeToRefs(permissionsStore); 
const elementsForCurrentRole = ref(getElementsForCurrentRole.value);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using the `storeToRefs` method here: `const { getElementsForCurrentRole, roles } = storeToRefs(permissionsStore);`. Do I handle something wrong here?

Comment: I already updated my answer.

Comment: The value of `elementsForCurrentRole` is undefined here.. mhh..

Comment: I think it's caused by `getters.getElementsForCurrentRole` return undefined.

Comment: Nope, just checked it. It returns an array of 57 objects. I noticed that when I change the route and come back to re-init, the output appears, but: all changes are ignored from the store. The element is not reactive anymore. How strange is that...?

Comment: Because the state (**elementsForCurrentRole**)  belongs to the component, you did not update it on pinia. If you want to directly change the state on pinia, it must come from pinia.

Comment: Yes, I tried exactly that with the initial code from my post. So.. if I can't do this with a getter, which way could I go to get exact the output from the `getElementsForCurrentRole`, but reactive to the store?

Comment: I've added a workaround to the main post. Its okay, but not really clean I think..